# Text Alignment in Jasper with HTML markup

Tags: html, jasper-reports, alignment, text-alignment

I want to align text for static text with html markup. I tried for 
p tag with both align and text-align property. Seems that both does not take effect.

```
<p align="right">Right 1</p> <p text-align:right>Right 2</p>
```

[image]

I know that jasper report supports very few of html tags according to
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539009/html-tags-supported-jasper-reports-v-371

Is is possible to achieve this on japser version 6.0.3?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<textField>` with `<textElement markup="html"/>` you can only format how the text looks. (color,bold,underline ecc).

**This feature is for producing styled text**.

[Quoting](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/536494/alignment-style-left-right-center-html-markup-doesnt-work-when-produce-pdf) Teodord (jasper report staff)

> The alignment is not among supported styling because it is not about
>   how text **characters look**, but about how you lay them out. We cannot
>   change the alignment of text within the same text field element.

However you could test the `<hc:html>` component, this will render an image of you html.

**Note:** this is not correct html `<p text-align:right>` it should be `<p style='text-align:right'>`, but it will not make any difference.

Comment: <p style='text-align:right'> does not work

Comment: @Lucke exactly, *but it will not make any difference*, hence read the answer again to understand why not